# Email attachment is blank

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to attach a file to outlook using VBA, however my code always seems to attach a blank file.

The code currently saves a workbook in a pre-defined path and then adds a file by the same name as an attachment to outlook but the file attached is blank and I'm not sure why. This "blank" file does not appear to be saved anywhere by the code so not sure where it is coming from.

```
Dim NewWkb As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim COB As Variant
    COB = Range("B16").Value
    COB = Format(COB, "DD_MMM_YYYY") 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add
NewWkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\Documents\BS_Spray " & COB
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy NewWkb.Worksheets(NewWkb.Worksheets.Count)
Next
Sheets("sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = " "
    .Subject = "SL Utility B/S Report " & J
    .Body = "Hi all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see attached  " & J
    .Attachments.Add NewWkb.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Is there intentionally a space (" ") after `BS_Spray` and the `COB` variable?  What is the value of `NewWkb.FullName` if you were to display/debug it right before your `With OutMail`?

Comment: The space is intentional so that there is a space in the subject before the date is inserted. I tried debug.peint newwkb but it did not give an output?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass "`C:\Users\Documents\BS_Spray " & COB` to `.Attachments.Add`

Comment: Tried that but the code does not attach any file to the email now :/

Comment: Does it raise an exception?

Comment: No exception, code runs fine but it adds text to the attachment field but no actual attachment

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it adds text to the attachment field but no actual attachment". How can text be added instead of an attachment?

Comment: To be honest i am not sure how but in the attachment field it says "bs spray" in text form, no attachment

Comment: If you look at the message (save it first) with OutlookSpy (click IMessage), what do you see in the GetAttachmentTable tab?